# The latest version of Google Chrome, 73.0, the overflow in web applications does not work anymore

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll, overflow

The latest version of Google Chrome, 73.0, the overflow in web applications does not work anymore used without specifying height 100% on the containers. Is this is a bug ?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3101009?hl=en

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: To be clear: It would help enormously if you **create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**, so that people can answer your question.

Comment: To be even clearer: nobody knows what you mean by "the overflow in web applications" and how it "does not work anymore". It would be best if you could make an [MCVE](/help/mcve) and show us, but if not, at least use your words and tell us. Don't expect us to read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it is, someone has already written about it.

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3101009?hl=en

Comment: I have already mentioned in the in the question as comment , i need solution .
The same thing is working in firefox

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this Chromium bug report thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=927066) regarding this issue.

Someone recommended on that thread to set `min-height: 0` on the container, or `max-height: 100%` on the children, which would solve the overflow issue.

For future reference and other users, here is a fiddle reproducing the issue, copied from the Chromium bug report thread.

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
         Box 1
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box">
         Box 2 (Nested)    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```